# Range of correlation proof

Tags: statistics, correlation

> $$V(aX+bY)=a^2V(X)+2ab \space\text{Cov}(X,Y)+b^2V(Y).$$
> Now, althoug $X$ and $Y$ are not constant (so $V(X)>0,V(Y)>0$), it is possible for $aX+bY$ to be constant, in wich case $V(aX+bY)$ would be zero.Therefor $$V(aX+bY)\ge0,$$thus $$a^2V(X)+2ab \space\text{Cov}(X,Y)+b^2V(Y)\ge 0.$$

I was hoping someone could explain this to me. It is to do with proof that the range of correlation is between $1$ and $-1.$

I am not sure what it means to claim that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not constant? Does this simply mean not all values are the expected value of $Y$ or $X$ because the variance is given by

$$V(N) = E(n - E(n))^2$$

Additionally, why is it possible for $aX + bY$ to be constant?

Would very much appreciate anyone's insight.

Comment: What if $Y=X$ always?  Then $a=1, b=-1$ satisfy $aX+bY=0$ always.

Comment: Agreed. So what is it meant by 'constant'? That aX + bY = some constant value for all X and Y?

Comment: Constant, not random.  $X$ might be the daily temperature, measured in Celsius, and $Y$ might be the same thing but measured in Fahrenheit.  The are related by $9X-5Y$ being the same, no matter what $X$ was.  $X$ and $Y$ are different each day, but the value of $9X-5Y$ is always the same.

Comment: Thank you for this!